# How to simultaneously compress a vector (with duplicates) while keeping track of the original indices?

Tags: c++, stl

Say I have a vector `{1,3,1,5,4,2,3,4,5,2}` (the vector size could be very big),

```
indices --> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
values  --> 1 3 1 5 4 2 3 4 5 2
```

Which has a relation as:

```
1 --> {1,3}
2 --> {6,10}
3 --> {2,7}
4 --> {5,8}
5 --> {4,9}
```

Now using set, I can reduce it to `{1,2,3,4,5}` by,

```
std::set<int> uniqNumbersSet;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < uniqNumbers.size(); ++i )
{
    uniqNumbersSet.insert(uniqNumbers[i]);
}
uniqNumbers.assign(uniqNumbersSet.begin(), uniqNumbersSet.end());
```

But how can I keep track of their original relations? Any efficient ways using STL?

Comment: vectors have no keys. So it is not clear what relation are you talking about?

Comment: _has a mapping relation as_… You said it: maybe a `std::map` with unique values as keys and vectors as values is what you need? Or, better, a `boost::container::multimap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `map` of `vector`.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

std::map<int, std::vector<unsigned> > uniqNumMap;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < uniqNumbers.size(); ++i) {
    uniqNumMap[uniqNumbers[i]].push_back(i+1);
}

for (std::map<int, std::vector<unsigned> >::const_iterator i = uniqNumMap.begin(); i != uniqNumMap.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i->first << " --> {";
    for (std::vector<unsigned>::const_iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); ++j) {
        if (j != i->second.begin()) std::cout << ",";
        std::cout << *j;
    }  
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```